# How can I make site-wide content editable, for example footer content

Tags: customization, templates

I'm new to wordpress, but I have enough developer experience. (the first thing I did was to get a blank template (blankslate) to start building up this wp site).

I want to understand what are the options for content that will be present on several templates. For now, think about the footer. I want to be able to edit its content using an HTML editor (like the post content editor).

I will be creating the templates myself. I need something that using the WP control panel will allow me to populate some sort of 'key-value' thing. Inside the templates ideally I would be able to do `get_content('key')` and I will get the contents for it.

Have in mind that this should not be POST or PAGE specific. I want to be able to access it from any template, and not to be related to a specific POST or PAGE. This is why custom fields won't help.

So, what plugins can help me? Is this something that is already integrated into wordpress?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say there are [Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) as well as [Widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *numerous* storage mechanisms in WordPress, issue mostly is you might not be making right calls which one to use until you get some practical experience with them.

*Very* loosely they are (from more user–facing to more developer–facing):

- posts/page and custom posts types — for post–like content
- widgets and sidebars they are going in — for “blocks” of things
- post meta — for content–related data which isn't actual primary textual content
- options — for arbitrary key/value store

There are more, but one of these is likely what you want for starters. Note that *all* of them can be used in varied ways. Custom post types (CPTs) can be *very* different from “normal” posts.

While direct plugin recommendations are not considered in scope here, from development point of view (which happens to match your requirements pretty close), I would suggest to look at [Spots](https://wordpress.org/plugins/spots/) plugin.

Comment: Spots Plugin looks like what I'm looking for! I'm going to try it.